# drupal 8 show field twice

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-8, drupal-templates

I created a custom bundle (content type) and I've created fields

One of those field is a file type field, is a video file, stored in the private storage. I installed the [videojs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) to allow to watch the video.

I need to show this field twice in the node page. One in the generic file formatter that allows the user to download the file, and I also need to play the video. I decided to set up as generic file formatter and customize the twig template to show again with the video player.

I achieve to show twice with the settings formatter (generic file) with this code in the node--mybundle--full.html.twig template

```
{{ content.field_sd_video }}
```

I thought it would be something easy like field+formatter:

```
{{ content.field_sd_video|videojs_formatter }}
```

But I can't find what is the simple way to achieve this. May be it's necesary more a tricky way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, I put this code in preprocess node function. It has to be easy, but not easy to know how ;)

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

     $variables['video_caption'] = $variables['node']->get('field_video')
         ->view(array(
            'label' => 'hidden',
            'type' => 'videojs_player_list'
        ));
}
```

and I only has to add this line in twig file:

```
{{ video_caption }}
```

in my case node--mybundle--full.html.twig template

For those arrive here looking for something similar
I was inspired by [Twig Recipes](http://2016.drupalcorn.org/sites/default/files/slides/Twig%20Recipies%20-%20DrupalCorn%202016.pdf) on page 41
It was usefull for me [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates). Playing with kint and node variable and the classes used to wrap the information. Then I found that the field comes with [FileFieldItemList] and then I found the view method that uses [EntityViewBuilderInterface]